# All of a sudden str.decode('unicode_escape') stopped working [2.7.3]

Tags: python, unicode

This snippet is taken from my recent python work. And it used to work just fine

```
strr = "What is th\u00e9 point?"
print strr.decode('unicode_escape')
```

But now it throws the unicode decoding error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenon\Documents\WorkDir\pyWork\ocrFinale\F1\tests.py", line 49, in <module>
    print strr.decode('unicode_escape')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the possible cause of this?

Comment: Are you using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` perhaps?

Comment: Wow.. So this is a windoz nuisance?    @MartijnPieters nope

Comment: @vvy: yet that's the only way you can reproduce your problem; `strr` is *already a `unicode` object*.

Comment: @vvy You must be using some pluggin in your editor which adds that stuff

Comment: The error message says you're decoding to ASCII ("'ascii' codec can't encode ...").  And Python means ASCII in a very strict sense; not Latin-1.  The character you want is in Latin-1 and not ASCII.

Comment: @BhargavRao You Awesome man! Problem traced. The culprit is 'sublime text'  I started using it today only.

Comment: @MaxLybbert Thats a very helpful insight. Untill now I hadn't given this a thought. I will be more careful with the data-set in db. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have enabled unicode literals or have created a *Unicode* object by another means, by mistake.

The `strr` value is *already* a unicode object, so in order to decode the value Python first tries to *encode* to a byte string.

If you have an actual byte string your code works:

```
>>> strr = "What is th\u00e9 point?"
>>> strr.decode('unicode_escape')
u'What is th\xe9 point?'
```

but as soon as `strr` is in fact a Unicode object, you get the error as Python tries to *encode* the object using the default ASCII codec first:

```
>>> strr.decode('unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It could be that you enabled `unicode_literals`, for example:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> strr = "What is th\u00e9 point?"
>>> type(strr)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> strr.decode('unicode_escape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. I tried running the code from dos prompt and it doesn't complain. The 'sublime text' editor was converting my text to unicode behind the scene.

Comment: @vvy: Sublime Text 3 uses *Python 3*; you'd get a completely different error however.

Comment: @vvy Coincidently this happened to another user a few hours back in the Python chat room

Comment: @BhargavRao Thats funny. For a while I checked my git checkouts, but it was same there. I literally spelled the characters at the slowest pace I could and..I am sure I couldn't have traced the culprit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am using 'sublime text 2' (now only for source editing). I didn't install any plugin in sublime I started using it today only. Does it come pre-installed?

Comment: @vvy: no, it doesn't; it seems to be another package, but you'd install it with Package Control, it shouldn't be there out of the box. But I use Sublime Text 3, haven't used ST2 in ages.

Comment: @vvy: the [Python2UnicodeFixer package](https://github.com/allieus/Python2UnicodeFixer/) would insert the `unicode_literals` line automatically.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I couldn't locate the specified package in the 'packages folder'. I think the console box used by 'sublime text 2' to display the program output doesn't support unicode.

Comment: @vvy: the Sublime Text 2 console may well have `from __future__ import unicode_literals` enabled. The console is for *Sublime plugins*, not for your own Python code, per se.